# Math formula for finding 'HH:MM:SS:MMM' Timecode given a number of frames and FPS?

Tags: timecode

I have been at this for a few days and while I have made progress I am stuck on the last bit, getting timecode to display as `HH:MM:SS:MS` rather than `HH:MM:SS:FF`. To do this I need a formula for the milliseconds part

I know this is will be complicated for Drop-Frame Timecodes so I have ruled them out. I am only concerned with NDF Timecodes.

The formula I have for finding a NDF Timecode, for example a video of 30 frames with a 12 FPS:

1. To get the hours, `30 / (12* 3600)`, `3600` is the number of seconds in a hour
2. To get the minutes, `30 / (12 * 60) - (0 * 60)`, `0` is the sum from step 1
3. To get the seconds, `(30 / 12) - ( (0 * 3600) - (0 * 60)`
4. To get the frames, `30 % 12` (Modulas)

The Timecode would be `00:00:02:06`, as shown at [Frames to Timecode Calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/other/frames-to-timecode?c=GBP&v=frames:30,fpses:12).

I would like to make a slight tweak at step 4, to instead get the milliseconds needed for format `HH:MM:SS:MMM`. I have tried to unsuccessfully solve it on my own, I searched around and turned up with nothing too.

I am not a math wizard by any chance, not even a half rate one. I would really like to learn how to do this though. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frames are fractions of a second, thus:

```
frameduration = 1 / framerate
framecomponent = totalframes % framerate
millisecondscomponent = framecomponent * frameduration * 1000
// finally
millisecondscomponent = ((totalframes % framerate) * 1000 ) / framerate
```

In your example:

```
millisecondscomponent = ((30 % 12) * 1000 ) / 12 = 500 ms
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I understand it much better now and can do it on my own.